# bracket's not in the right place?

Tags: javascript, brackets

i can't get the brackets right it is driving me crazy,
j = a variable i tried some but I cannot get it working I searched on the internet for it aswell. but there's is not a good tutorial on how to do those "" and ''.

```
kalender += "<td id="j' id='tabeldagen'>" + j;
```

Comment: btw, you can't have two id tags in an html element.

Comment: that explains alot! i tought i could. i will be working with classes than thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
kalender += "<td id='"+j+"' id='tabeldagen'>"+j;
```

If you are having a hard time figuring out how to concatenate strings with variables, I would first type the string without the variables. Then place the variables in after.

```
kalender += "<td id='' id='tabeldagen'>";
```

then

```
kalender += "<td id='"+j+"' id='tabeldagen'>"+j;
```

Comment: this seems logical, but it won't add the second Id of tabeldagen to the `<TD>`

Comment: Brainoverflow is correct. You can't have multiple id's in any html element. Maybe change one of them to name= instead of id=